# How to use Mat img on all function without calling function?

Tags: opencv

I want to use image which I used by **Mat img=imread("Nature.jpg");** to inside of all functions that are in the program, I think, this can be implemented as **Mat img** is defined such volatile variable, is this posible?

Comment: probably you meant "global" variable. But you really should avoid that. Either learn better OOP programming, or pass the `img` as input to all functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to declare a variable cv :: Mat as volatile, because if you are doing this surely these need to update this variable from different threads, if what you want is to use a type cv :: Mat global then type the following line outside of any function or class

```
cv::Mat img;
```

Now if you want to use this variable from another file you must write:

```
extern cv::Mat img;
```

Now if you need access multithreaded I recommend you look for a guide on mutex and multithreaded programming, because if two or more functions access the variable img at the same time your program will fail at runtime by segmentation violation.